# Can we bind [(ngModel)] from Angular 6 to JSONEditor

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I am using **Angular 6** for building my application. In this I have added JSONEditor from [ang-jsonEditor](https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor) NPM module. In this editor we have option to detect the change event using **onChange** method. The issue is This method will only be triggered when we are actually changing the contents of that Editor. In my case, I have some object which will be default at very first time and I am able to see that JSON object on the JSONEditor screen but I am not able to get that object . When I tries to fetched (without detecting change event) it gives me undefined. Can anybody help me to sort out this issue please ?

My Component ts file is :

```
public editorOptions: JsonEditorOptions;
@ViewChild(JsonEditorComponent) editor: JsonEditorComponent;

constructor() {
 this.editorOptions = new JsonEditorOptions();
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.editorOptions.onChange = () => {
  this.change();
};

change(): void {
   console.log(this.editor.getText());  
}
```

and my Component template file is as follows :

```
<div class="jsoneditor-wrapper" [ngClass]="cssClass">
<json-editor
[options]="editorOptions"
[data]="data">
```

Now in this case data from template file is nothing but the default value that will be displayed on JSON Editor screen at very first time. I wanted to access that data on an custom event that I am going to create.

Here it will be great if we can use [(ngModel)] to get the data.

Comment: Hey there! I'm from future. Any solution for this?